# Script that edits a texture2d to paint over a mask works in editor but not in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a script which uses raycasting to the mouse point to paint over a mask in the material to remove dirt on a item in game and it works in the editor fine but after I build it doesn't work

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {

            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out RaycastHit raycastHit))
            {
                Vector2 textureCoord = raycastHit.textureCoord;

                int pixelX = (int)(textureCoord.x * dirtMaskTexture.width);
                int pixelY = (int)(textureCoord.y * dirtMaskTexture.height);

                Vector2Int paintPixelPosition = new Vector2Int(pixelX, pixelY);
                Debug.Log("UV: " + textureCoord + "; Pixels: " + paintPixelPosition);

                int paintPixelDistance = Mathf.Abs(paintPixelPosition.x - lastPaintPixelPosition.x) + Mathf.Abs(paintPixelPosition.y - lastPaintPixelPosition.y);
                int maxPaintDistance = 7;
                if (paintPixelDistance < maxPaintDistance)
                {
                    // Painting too close to last position
                    return;
                }
                lastPaintPixelPosition = paintPixelPosition;


                int pixelXOffset = pixelX - (dirtBrush.width / 2);
                int pixelYOffset = pixelY - (dirtBrush.height / 2);

                for (int x = 0; x < dirtBrush.width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < dirtBrush.height; y++)
                    {
                        Color pixelDirt = dirtBrush.GetPixel(x, y);
                        Color pixelDirtMask = dirtMaskTexture.GetPixel(pixelXOffset + x, pixelYOffset + y);

                        float removedAmount = pixelDirtMask.g - (pixelDirtMask.g * pixelDirt.g);
                        
                        dirtMaskTexture.SetPixel(
                            pixelXOffset + x,
                            pixelYOffset + y,
                            new Color(0, pixelDirtMask.g * pixelDirt.g, 0)
                        );
                    }
                }

                dirtMaskTexture.Apply();

            }
```

After adding

```
Debug.Log("UV: " + textureCoord + "; Pixels: " + paintPixelPosition);
```

in unity this is what I get and how it should look when mouse raycasts onto the objects UV

```
UV: (0.49, 0.50)Pixels: (252, 257)
```

This is what I get in build

```
UV: (0.00, 0.00)Pixels: (0, 0)
```

Comment: Which platform you get build?

Comment: Windows, Mac, Linux

Comment: Add some `Debug.Log` commands and check the logs to see which part of the code is not being executed.

Comment: Thanks cant believe I didn't think of that, added the debug logs to the post

Comment: One thing to note too is the resolution the game tab is playing in inside of Unity's editor compared to what resolution you are playing with after the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, from what I've read apparently scripts in unity engine can access all the mesh data of objects but in build it has to be specified in the import settings of the 3d object, so I had to enable Read/Write on the fbx model import settings for the meshes that need to be accessed after build, now it works perfectly.

Comment: Do not hesistate to add some details other people facing the same problem would need. Then you can accept your own answer.